# Getting same value when I'm looking in different nodes HTMLAgility

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, html-agility-pack

I'm having a problem using html agility.
I stumbled upon an img src/ img alt where i have to take data.

All is good when there is only one thing i need to take my data, but when there are more it founds everything in the collection like it should, but the data taken is always from the 1st node in the collection...

```
HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='listHolder']//article[@class='brochure openBrochureAction']//div[@class='imgBrochure']");
                foreach (HtmlNode node in collection)
{
//Tried these examples:
NomeFolheto = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img[@alt]").GetAttributeValue("alt", "none").Trim();
string testeNome = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img/@alt").Attributes["alt"].Value;

string testeimagem = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img/@src").Attributes["src"].Value;
imagem = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img[@src]").GetAttributeValue("src", "none").Trim();
}
```

Like i said, the collection finds all nodes it should, and gets the 1st value properly, but when it goes for the other nodes, the values it gets are from the 1st node.

What am I doing wrong? I went to check each node in the collection, and they have same "alt" attribute like it should and different "src" attribute like they should, but I know because i debugged that it's picking up the 1st node every time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some example HTML?

Comment: Have you considered that each node in the `HtmlNodeCollection` has the sub-node that you are selecting in your for-each loop?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't over-writting the values in the for loop with each iteration?

Comment: Yes I was sure, because I didn't use that variable anywhere else only adding that value to a list and i did step by step debug of it.

The answer provided worked, didn't think it would be that easy, noob mistake i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath expressions are all starting from the root (of the document). Even when you have a reference to a single node, it is still just a reference to that node within the entire tree.

You should use `.//` for the expressions:

```
HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='listHolder']//article[@class='brochure openBrochureAction']//div[@class='imgBrochure']");
                foreach (HtmlNode node in collection)
{
//Tried these examples:
    NomeFolheto = node
        .SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img[@alt]")
        .GetAttributeValue("alt", "none").Trim();
    string testeNome = node
        .SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img/@alt")
        .Attributes["alt"].Value;

    string testeimagem = node
        .SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img/@src")
        .Attributes["src"].Value;
    imagem = node
        .SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='imageRatioHorizontal']//img[@src]")
        .GetAttributeValue("src", "none").Trim();
}
```